# Shiny filter works locally, application publishes fine, but filter has quirk when selecting two categories

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new here, so forgive me if I'm missing a protocol.
I am trying to deploy an application on rshiny. It deploys just fine, but the last tab called "Correlations" won't allow me to filter on my inputPicker for New Mexico (NM) or Puerto Rico (PR) The thing is, it WORKS when I run the app on my computer. It only won't work when it's published, so I'm not sure if it's a memory issue.

The link to the app is here:

https://marksresearch.shinyapps.io/IPEDS_Dash/

The isssue is on the last tab when you try to select NM or PR,it won't show on the weblink even though it DOES work on the local application. I've included my code below, but I was wondering, could this simply be a memory problem and an upgrade might fix it? I've shared my shiny code from rmarkdown code, which was recycled into a larger amount of code on Shiny.Both markdown and shiny work when I run them. It just doesn't work when it's published.  I can post my Shiny Code if needed. The data are on a .csv file. Getting them required a lot of munging from the U.S. Department of Education and the Census Bureau, but they are publicly available data and I can share them, though it will run if you run it. It just doesn't work when it's published!

Thank you so much for your help!!

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
Community<-read.csv("../Dashboard/ShinyFiles/Community.csv")


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    # Note the wrapping of the string in HTML()
    tags$style(HTML("
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yusei+Magic&display=swap');
      body {
        background-color: gray;
        color: white;
      }
      h2 {
        font-family: 'Zen Loop', 'regular 400';
      }
      .shiny-input-container {
        color: #111111;
      }"))
  ),
  headerPanel(("Correlations Between College and Community Attributes")),
  titlePanel("Refresh Your Browser to Reset Filters"),
  sidebarLayout( 
  sidebarPanel(width = 4,      
      tagList(   
    varSelectInput(
      inputId = "xvar",
      label = "Select an X variable",
      data = Community,
      selected = "County_Percent_Unemployed"),
    varSelectInput(
      inputId = "yvar",
      label = "Select a Y variable",
      data = Community,
      selected = "Median_Household_Income"),
    pickerInput("stateInput6", "Select a State:",
                     choices = sort(unique(Community$State)),
                     options = list('actions-box' = TRUE), multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = "WY"))),
  
    
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("plot6", height = 600)
      
    ) 
  ) )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  
  
output$plot6 <- renderPlotly({
  
  ab<- reactive({
    Community %>%
    filter(State %in% input$stateInput6)    
    
  }) 
  
    
  
 com<-  ggplot(ab(), aes_string(x = input$xvar, y =input$yvar))+ 
       stat_summary(aes(geom = "point", fun = "mean", color = Community_Type, label3 = State, label4= County, label5 = 
                          Institution))+
       geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))+
       scale_color_discrete(name = " ")
     ggplotly(com)
  
})


}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason those states would not work in the filter was because they contained words with non-English accents. Hence the logged error codes:

*Warning: Error in gsub: input string 467 is invalid in this locale*

I fixed the .csv manually, but I was wondering if there is something you can do in your shiny code to address this issue so you don't have to go back and fix it manually every time?

Thank you!
M

Comment: I figured out how to encode a column of data with accents and other marks. I just entered this;

Community$County<- iconv(Community$County, from = 'UTF-8', to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT')

Where Community is the dataframe and County is the variable or the name of the column. This resolved the issue and insures that this will be corrected any time I refresh my data.